# Magento 1.5.1.0 Multi-Store

Tags: magento

I am currently running version 1.5.1.0 of Magento and I would like to set up another store with the following:

1. Both stores using different domains
2. Shared shopping cart/checkout
3. Shared codebase

I don't have ssh access.

I have looked around and found a number of tutorials but they are for older versions or else require shell access.  Could someone point me in the direction of a tutorial specifically for 1.5.1.0 or provide instructions for completing this?

Comment: Does yourotherdomain.com point to the same directory on the Server As yourdomain.com? Do you have FTP access?

Comment: yourotherdomain.com can point to the same directory as yourdomian.com.  Also, I do have ftp access

Answer (score 1):

refer to http://blog.speedupmate.com/post/9992573819/poor-mans-multisite-setup-for-magento

refer to http://tweetorials.tumblr.com/post/9991125658/magento-multi-website-setup